# How to change text value after button click event Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

After click event on this button (code below)

```
<button (click)="login()" routerLink="/dashboard" class="btn btn-primary 
primary-login">Login with Google</button>
```

I wanted to change text value in header h1 to for example dashboard

```
<h1 class="oap__header--title"  >Welcome in Organizer App</h1>
```

Below is TypeScript code

```
login() {
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}
```

Is anyone knows how to achieve that ?? Probably this is really easy but I don't know how to start with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hardcode the string in your HTML, use a property of your component, like this:

`<h1 class="oap__header--title">{{ myString }}</h1>`

in the TS file you'll have:

```
myString: string = 'Welcome in Organizer App'
login() {
  this.myString = 'Dashboard'
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}
```